# how to send text(command) via Bluetooth to handle robot from android device?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

My actual req is controlling of robot from android device.
Voice to text conversion n send that commonds which matches the text. Say start -1 ,here 1 is command which I need to send to robot.....so can u please tell me the procedure to be followed.

is it possible to send only text instead of file??

Comment: So for conversion of voice to text , take a look at (`TextToSpeech`)[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html] in the android API , and for sending `signals` to robot it depends on the way you built your robot for example : if you're using Arduino , this one offers a nice API for handling sending signal over bluetooth ...

Comment: @FouadWahabi, Why don't you post this as an answer ?

Comment: @JonasCz because it's not a complete answer and I don't have enough knowledge to give examples and full explanation ;)

Comment: look at the android bluetooth chat example.  It sends strings back and forth over bluetooth.  Now you have all your pieces.  the bluettoth and the texttospeech.

Answer (score 2):

There are three parts to what you have described: [hotword detection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/voice/package-summary.html), a [bluetooth server](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothServerSocket.html), and a [bluetooth client](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html). What follows is a short description of what this envolves.

For the hotword detection, this will require registering a service for your hotword. When your hotword is recognized Android will call your service.

For the bluetooth server, depending on how it is set up either side could be the server. To create a listening bluetooth server socket, use [BluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.UUID%29) and then call [accept()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothServerSocket.html#accept%28%29). This is blocking meaning don't use it in your main thread.

For the bluetooth client, once again depending on how it is set up either side could be the client. To connect to a listening bluetooth server socket, you can use [BluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord%28java.util.UUID%29) and call [connect()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#connect%28%29).

Once a bluetooth connection is established you can send and retrive data (for example a string) using [input](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) and [output](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) streams.

When you are done with your connections don't forget to close the sockets.

Any bluetooth device will have something similar. So if it's not an Android powered robot, you will have to look into the specific API for that device.

For additional learning about bluetooth communication between two Android devices, have a look at the Android bluetooth [API guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) and sample [BluetoothChat](http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html).

Cheers!

Comment: Please more links in you answer.  Especially to the methods. :)